# Uploadify and ASP.net MVC 4. Just a dream?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, uploadify

Is it possible to get [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to work with ASP.net MVC4?

I have the following in my view:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style = "padding:40px">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(window).load(
    function () {
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").uploadify({
            'swf': '/Assets/js/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': '/Main/UploadFiles/',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

And the following in my MainController.cs:

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
{
    AppHelper.SendEmail("myEmailAddress@email.com", "from@email.com", "Started upload", "body of message", false);
    return Content("uploaded.txt");
}
```

I am able to process data in the UploadFiles method once it is called. The problem is uploadify will never try to access `/Main/UploadedFiles/`.

What is the magic URL that I need to enter into the "uploader" setting for uploadify?

I have tried with and without `http://www.domain.com/`.

If I visit `/Main/Uploads/` in my web browser I will get an email.

Comment: Why are you using WebForm's `<asp:FileUpload />`? ASP.NET MVC doesn't use controls.

Comment: Is this what is causing my problem?

Comment: Check out this answer, might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853729/file-upload-and-persist-values-of-controls/18853907#18853907

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files uses HTTP's POST method, so you need to decorate your `UploadFiles` action with the [`HttpPostAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Also, you'll want to add a parameter to your action that allows you to access the uploaded file.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
{
    // ...
```

Comment: I've added this but the UploadFiles method still never gets called.

Comment: Then perhaps you need to use the web inspector to figure out what URL is getting called and what the server is responding with.

Comment: The request is made in flash so it does not show up in the web inspector

Comment: Then you should use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or a similar tool to monitor the outgoing connections.